# C++ : syntax for passing iterator to a function?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am making a class which is a kind of container and I would like to make a constructor that can take a "first" and "last" iterator like std::vector and other standard containers. What would be the correct syntax ? (I want a template a function that can take any first/last iterator types available (like the standard library I think). Thank you very much !

As an example, I want something like that :

```
template<class ...> MyClass(... first, ... last)
```

But what are the ... ?

Thank you very much.

Regarding the first answer :
I want a specific constructor that takes iterators as argument (because I have already constructors that take values and pointers as arguments)

EDIT :
Is something like this ok ?

```
template<class T1, class T2> MyClass(std::iterator<T1, T2> first, std::iterator<T1, T2> last)
```

Comment: There is no syntax requirements, but it would be polite of you if it implied the type concept. Something like `InputIterator` or `ForwardIterator`...

Comment: Regarding your edit: A template can take any type, so you can pass an iterator just fine, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: You mean something similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075374/iterators-and-templates

Comment: I have already a constructor of the form : template<class T1, class T2> MyClass(T1 x, T2 y) and I want a specific constructor for iterators. But I dont know the syntax for declaring a generic iterator...

Comment: You have a big design problem, then. A "generic iterator" type is just a template, as I pointed out in my answer. You could restrict the template so that *only* iterators may get passed, but you have an ambiguity situation with your other constructor then. What is that other constructor used for specifically?

Comment: I add an example in my question. By generic iterator, I mean something derived from a std::iterator.

Comment: There is no `std::iterator` class, and no other common iterator base.

Comment: @Xeo: There is actually an `std::iterator`, but you don't derive from it to get a common sub-type. It's purely for convenience -- it automatically defines all the normal `typedef`s for you (reference_type, value_type, difference_type, etc.)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: D'oh, right. Nvm my last comment then.

Comment: @Xeo: On a (minor) technicality you were actually correct: `std::iterator` isn't a class, it's a template. There's no common iterator base, because each instantiation of that template over different types is a completely separate type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can do what you want by taking advantage of the fact that `std::iterator`'s have a member named `iterator_category`.  Combine this with [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) and you get something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class X>
class my_class {
public:
    my_class(X a, X b) {
        std::cout << "in my_class(X,X)" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class Iter>
    my_class(Iter a, Iter b, typename Iter::iterator_category *p=0) {
        std::cout << "in my_class(Iter,Iter)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main()
{
    char buf[] = "foo";
    std::vector<char> v;

    my_class<int> one(1, 2);
    my_class<char*> two(&buf[0], &buf[3]);
    my_class<char> three(v.begin(), v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
in my_class(X,X)
in my_class(X,X)
in my_class(Iter,Iter)
```

Comment: Excellent ! I didn't know SFINAE, and it can be very useful

Comment: Except that pointers are perfectly valid iterators and obviously don't have a `iterator_category` typedef.

Comment: Actually that syntax solves my specific problem, but good point Xeo

Comment: @Xeo _"pointers are valid iterators"_ really depends on your definition of an iterator.  If you define it as having the members of `std::iterator`, then a pointer isn't a very good iterator

Comment: `iterator_traits` exists exactly for cases like this. That's why you should use `typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` instead of just `Iter::iterator_category`.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Except that iterators are modelled after pointers and that's a very important property.

Comment: @sbabbi: Except that you get a hard error when `Iter` is not an iterator, instead of the desired SFINAE soft error.

Answer (score 6):

The `...` can be whatever you want, it's just a placeholder name for whatever the type will be. I think you need to read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/500104).

```
template<class Iter> MyClass(Iter first, Iter last)
```

`Iter` is a common name if the type should represent an iterator. Another option might be `InIt` to signal that the iterators should not be output iterators.

Comment: twas not me, but perhaps it should be typename Iter?

Comment: @helloworld922: Nope, `class` and `typename` are synonymous when used for template parameters. Note, however, that you can only use `class` when you have a template template parameter: `template<template<typename> class TemplClass>`.

Comment: @helloworld922, neither is really better than the other per se. The class is just kind of left over.

Comment: `class` works fine here. In *Modern C++ Design*, Andre suggests a convention of using `typename` when any type can be passed, and `class` when a user-defined type is required, but that never seems to have really caught on.